# Read a JSON or XML file in a JSP page and pass to Spring controller

Tags: java, json, xml, spring, jsp

I have an application which needs to read contents of a JSON or XML file and then send the JSON or XML to a Spring controller so that data can be processed. I'm not really sure where to start with this. I don't believe it is possible to send the file itself to the controller (uploading it but not saving it on the server). What would be the best approach?

Comment: Your requirements are not clear. Do you want to upload a file to the server? do you want to make a JSON request to your server?

Comment: There will be a file client side. This file will contain either JSON or XML. Ultimately I want the contents of this file available server side. Either by extracting the contents on the client side and sending them over, or by sending the whole file over and reading it server side

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using ajaxSubmit.

Over-rode the submit functionality of the form using ajaxSubmit which then uploaded a MultiPart file object to the controller. This can then be turned into a temporary file on the server and processed.